# Excel VBA macro - how to combine 2 sheets the most efficient way

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have three sheets. Two of them contain data to be written into the third one.

Sheet A has the following structure:

```
|    A    |   B  |  C |  D |  E |   F   |
| Version | Name | XX | XY | XZ | DATA  |
|   5.0   | Test | XX | XY | XZ | test1 |
|   5.1   | Tree | XX | XY | XZ |  100  |
|   5.1   | Test | XX | XY | XZ | test  |
|   5.0   | Tree | XX | XY | XZ |  50   |
...
```

Sheet B has this:

```
|    A    |   B  |  C |  D |  E   |
| Version | Name | XX | XY | DATA |
|   5.1   | Test | XX | XY | test |
|   5.0   | tree | XX | XY | 300  |
|   5.1   | tree | XX | XY | 400  |
|   5.0   | Test | XX | XY | test |
...
```

And Sheet C has this:

```
|   A  |  B |       C      |       D      |  E |       F      |      G       | H  | ..
| Name | XX | SheetA - 5.0 | SheetB - 5.0 | XX | SheetA - 5.1 | SheetB - 5.1 | XX | ..
...
```

XX/XY/XZ = random data. Versions are strings and from 5.0 - 5.9. (actual the versions are years, but I think its more simple this way)

---

Now I want to combine Sheet A and Sheet B into Sheet C. It should look like this:

```
|   A  |  B |       C      |       D      |  E |       F      |      G       | H  | ..
| Name | XX | SheetA - 5.0 | SheetB - 5.0 | XX | SheetA - 5.1 | SheetB - 5.1 | XX | ..
| test | XX |    test1     |     test     | XX |     test     |     test     | XX | ..
| Tree | XX |      50      |      300     | XX |      100     |      400     | XX | ..
…
```

Currently I just take Sheet A and put it in the Right spot in Sheet C.
This doesn't take too much time but now I want to get Sheet B also into Sheet C so my current solution is to loop each row from Sheet B, find the row with the same name in Column "A" and fill the gaps.
The problem is, that each Sheet has 150k+ rows and this takes way too much time. And also there are names in Sheet B that aren't in Sheet C so the ".find" function search the whole 150k+ rows, the speed of this is like ~3 rows per second. Is there a quicker way?

Code example how I fill Sheet B into Sheet C: (Code from A to C is nearly the same)

```
For Each Row In DataFromSheetB.Rows
    With Selection
        Set FindRow = Sheets("C").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Row.Cells(2), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With
    If FindRow Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Skip2
    Else
        Select Case Row.Cells(1)
        Case "5.0"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.1"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(7).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.2"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(10).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.3"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(13).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.4"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(16).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.5"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(19).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.6"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(21).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.7"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(24).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.8"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(27).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        Case "5.9"
            FindRow.EntireRow.Cells(30).Value = Row.Cells(5)
        End Select
    End If
Skip2:
Next Row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually do is to issue ~150K^2/2 comparisons (~1E10), so I think there is no computer that could make it fast. You should approach it in a more scientific way like employing more efficient searching methods.

So if you are sure that `Name+Version` pairs are unique throughout all sheets, and you want to find the matching pairs, you can do the following:

1. Make an array of the pairs (=name+version) of sheet A and the row numbers by Dimming Idx(1 to 150000, 1 to 2) and put cstr(name+version) to (,1) and excel row number to (,2). Then sort this array with e.g. quicksort to make a unique sorted list.
2. Take each row in sheet B, make the key, and find it with e.g. binary search in the index.
3. Now you know the matching rows in sheet A and sheet B.

Alternatively, you can sort one of the sheets on name+version keys in order to use binary search. 
Good luck.